# Spring path with variable number of segments

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring application that stores objects and attributes, and provides paths to access them, in the form `/application-root/{object}/{attribute}`.

A new change is to allow objects to contain child objects within attributes. A user should be able to access data with a path like this:

`/application-root/{object1}/{attribute1}/{object2}/{attribute2}/{object3}/{attribute3}`...

There is no hard limit on how deep an object can be nested, so I need to be able to handle a  path with a variable number of segments and extract the information from the objects and attributes from it.

I've looked at the regular expressions in PathPattern class, but it looks like it that regex will only match a single segment.

What's the best way to handle a variable number of path segments in Spring?

Answer (score 2):

Options: *@see* *[PathPattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html)*

An example:

```java
@RestController
class DemoController {
    
    // Spring Boot 2.3 or lower
    @GetMapping("/search/**")
    public String search(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getRequestURI();
    }
    
    // Spring Boot 2.4 or higher
    @GetMapping("/find/{*mapping}")
    public String find(@PathVariable("mapping") String mapping ) {
        return mapping;
    }
}
```

`curl "http://localhost:8080/search/1/2/3/4"` will output `/search/1/2/3/4`

`curl "http://localhost:8080/find/1/2/3/4"` will output `/1/2/3/4`

From here on you could parse/map the String to your objects/attributes

Comment: The first options works, but not the second, but I think that will be good enough. From what I've read, PathPattern became available in Spring 5.3, this application is still on 5.2.x.

Comment: Strange [5.2.1.RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html) shows: `{*spring} matches zero or more path segments until the end of the path and captures it as a variable named "spring"`

Comment: @DirkDeyene: We're on 5.2.7.RELEASE so I guess we _should_ have it... very strange that it doesn't work. :/

Comment: Oh, it looks like the config property to enable PathPattern was introduced in Spring Boot 2.4 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21694), but we're still on 2.3.  I guess I'll have to find some other way to enable the PathPattern parser.

Comment: The only option left is to use  `@GetMapping("/xxx/**")` and filter out the path via `HttpServletRequest request`...

Answer (score 1):

If using a PathPattern like Dirk mentioned is not an option due to version differences, you might be able to use a [`ServletUriComponentsBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/ServletUriComponentsBuilder.html) to retrieve the path segments in a list:

```java
@RestController
public class SomeController {

    @GetMapping("/application-root/**")
    public void someEndpoint(HttpServletRequest request) {

        List<String> pathSegments = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromRequest(request).build().getPathSegments();

        // Remove "/application-root" by sublisting it as the returned list is immutable
        pathSegments.subList(1, pathSegments.size())
    }
}
```